# How to read the Kinect v2 IR sensor using Opencv in python

Tags: python, opencv, kinect-v2

I am able to get the RGB camera to work but not the IR sensor
Here's the code that allows me to use the RGB camera

```
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while vid.isOpened():
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    if not ret:
       break

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Your question is quite vague. Do you know how to read the Kinect's IR sensor at all? If so, please add your code. Is your question about how to *process* the images with OpenCV? Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.